getting the x,y coordinates of level 1 of contour
I am trying to extract the main axes of an elipse fitted to a cell image from a microscope. After capturing only the contour lines of the cell , I've fitted an elipse. now I am trying to extract a,b , so I've tried getting the x,y of the elipse shape and from there get a and b but I've failed. Also tried extracting from the equation but it also failed.
this is my current code:
`
coords = test_coords[0]
# for coords in test_coords:
x_orig, y_orig = coords
image[y_orig, x_orig] = 255
ROI = image[y_orig - 25:y_orig + 25, x_orig - 25:x_orig + 25]

# Find indices of black points (where pixel value is 0)
black_indices = np.where(ROI == 0)

# Extract x and y coordinates of black points
X = black_indices[1].reshape(-1, 1)  # Reshape to a column vector
X -= 25
Y = black_indices[0].reshape(-1, 1)  # Reshape to a column vector
Y -= 25
# Formulate and solve the least squares problem ||Ax - b ||^2
A = np.hstack([X**2, X * Y, Y**2, X, Y])
b = np.ones_like(X)
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)[0].squeeze()  # Use rcond=None for compatibility

# Print the equation of the ellipse in standard form
print('The ellipse is given by {0:.3}x^2 + {1:.3}xy + {2:.3}y^2 + {3:.3}x + {4:.3}y = 1'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))

# Plot the noisy data
plt.scatter(X, Y, label='Data Points')

# Plot the least squares ellipse
x_coord = np.linspace(-50,50, 3000)
y_coord = np.linspace(-50,50, 3000)
X_coord, Y_coord = np.meshgrid(x_coord, y_coord)
Z_coord = x[0] * X_coord ** 2 + x[1] * X_coord * Y_coord + x[2] * Y_coord**2 + x[3] * X_coord + x[4] * Y_coord

# Plot the contour of the ellipse
#plt.contour(X_coord, Y_coord, Z_coord, levels=1, colors='r', linewidths=1)
contour = plt.contour(X_coord, Y_coord, Z_coord, levels=1, colors='r', linewidths=1)
contour_points = contour.collections[0].get_paths()[0].vertices
x_points = contour_points[:, 0]
y_points = contour_points[:, 1]

plt.scatter(x_points, y_points, color='b', label='Points on Level 1 Contour')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Points on Level 1 Contour of the Ellipse')
plt.show()

`

